# Gradle hides files on building war

Tags: java, gradle, war

My project tree:

```
 /project
|
|--> /src
|    |-->/main
|        |-->/webapp
|            |--> a lot of folders here including /files with doc file inside
|--> build.gradle
```

when i put in my build.gradle file only `apply plugin 'war'` it puts everything in war file on build except doc file from `/files` directory

I read Gradle [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) so I'm adding

```
war{
    from 'src/main/webapp/files'
}
```

to my build.gradle file, after it my war file became bigger in size but needed file is not there.

How can I add file from `/files` directory to war `/files` directory?

**UPDATE**

After adding this project to multi-project build the problem has gone. Don't know really what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you're looking for is:

```
war {
  from 'src/main/webapp/files' into 'files'
}
```

This will copy everything from `src/main/webapp/files` into a subdirectory called `files` at the root of your WAR file (eg. `my-app.war/files`)

I had a lot of interesting issues with Gradle's `war` task and copying, so if this doesn't work, I can look up what other methods I've used.

Comment: Nope, now it makes me war with `/files` at the root and everything except document from `webapp/files` there. And I don't need `/files` at the root. I just need to have this file from `webapp/files` to be in war with the same structure. May be gradle ignores `.doc` files? There is `fileMode` property in [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:fileMode) , but which mode should I use?

Comment: Your question didn't explain clearly what you want. Do you want `src/main/webapp/files/*.doc` to copy to `my-app.war/webapp/files`?

Comment: I want to copy to war root everything from `src/main/webapp` including `webapp/files/*.doc`, now it copies everything right, except that `*.doc` file. My problem is in ignoring that `*.doc` file only, I need it.

Comment: Try adding `include '**/*'` or `include '**/*.doc'` under your `from` call.